# Möbius strip covering space of Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, covering-spaces

I've recently heard that the Möbius strip (without boundary) is a covering space of the Klein bottle. Honestly, I cannot see that. Any help to check this fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the Klein bottle $K$ as $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with its opposite sides identified, the top and bottom sides by $(x,0)\sim(x,1)$ and the left and right sides by $(0,x)\sim(1,1-x)$. Similarly, think of the open Möbius strip $M$ as $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}$ where the left and right edges are identified by $(0,x)\sim(1,-x)$.  There is then an easy covering map $M\to K$: just take the second coordinate mod $1$.